# Access SQL Server CUBE with Java

Tags: java, sql-server, olap-cube

I have created Data Cube with Sql Server, and I want to know if there is a possibility to access the data of this cube from a Java application using JDBC, I want a result like I browse the cube from Visual studio or Power Pivot in Excel.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jdbc4olap](http://www.jdbc4olap.org/) which provides a JDBC driver or take a look at [olap4j](http://www.olap4j.org/) which has an own API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to implement a solution in a JAVA application, I already implement the **olap4j** in my application and test it with MySQL connection and it works (I create the cube with pentaho cube designer) but now I have the cube created with SSAS, so I need to access data from this cube, I don't know if it's possible with **olap4j** to directly access a cube in sql server

Comment: @ELOUFIRHatim try this tutorial http://www.matthewgodding.com/articles/2010/2/27/getting-data-from-sql-analysis-services-using-java-and-olap4.html

Comment: DriverManager.getConnection(
        ""); what should i pass here i have Cube and the its running as a windows authentication